# Function inversion (analytical)

Tags: functions, inverse, hypergeometric-function, lambert-w, analytic-functions

Can $t(x)$ be found from: $$A \, t + B\ln\frac{1-t}{t}=x \; ?$$ Here, $A>0, \; B < 0$ and $0 \lt t \lt 1$.

The $t(x)$ should be given in analytical form (even if you use, say, Lambert's W - function).

PS: Such an expression (left hand side) appears as the complex phase in the integral representation of the confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind $_1F_1$, as used in the Coulomb wave function for positive energies.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with $t(\frac{A}{2}):=\frac{1}{2}$.

Derivation by $x$:

$t'(x)=\frac{1}{A-B(\frac{1}{1-t(x)}+\frac{1}{t(x)})}$

$t'(\frac{A}{2})=\frac{1}{A-4B}$

And so on: Taylor series with the development point $\frac{A}{2}$.

EDIT:

If you set $t(x+\frac{A}{2})-\frac{1}{2}:=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty x^k a_k$ (=> $a_0=0$) then you’ll get a recurrence formula for $a_{k+1}$ by using the equation $(t-\frac{1}{2})’(-A(t-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{A}{4}-B)=\frac{1}{4}-(t-\frac{1}{2})^2$.

It's more convenient to use $a_1$ instead of $\frac{1}{A-4B}$.

Comment: This is an useful approach. I used it sometimes in other contexts. However, it is numerical in nature (ODE). It is not harmless: eg, what happens if $A=4B$? Or if the denominator is zero? (the algebraic ODE solvers in my experience are not easily handling this...)

Comment: $A=4B$ cannot happen because of $A>0$ and $B<0$.

Comment: In this particular case, you are right.  In general, one can get across such situation though, hence the ODE would need special numerical approach.

Comment: You can have different Taylor series, e.g. set $t(\frac{A}{4}+B\ln3):=\frac{1}{4}$. Then we get $t’(\frac{A}{4}+B\ln3)=\frac{1}{A-\frac{16}{3}B}$ (and so on) and $A=4B$ is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\L{\operatorname L}$
Substitute $t=\frac1{w+1}$:
$$At+B\ln\left(\frac{1-t}t\right)=x\implies t+a\ln\left(\frac1t-1\right)=b\iff e^\frac1{w+1}w^b=a$$

Therefore [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) gives:

$$t=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^\frac{an}b}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}\frac1{t^2}e^{-\frac n{b t}}\right|_1$$

expanding $e^y$ as a series, differentiating, and summing gives [Laguerre $\L_n^u(x)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LaguerreL3/). Since $\L_{n-1}^1(x)=-\frac d{dx}\L_n(x)$, we use a [Laguerre $\L_n(x)$ integral representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LaguerreL/07/01/01/0001/), differentiate, and evaluate the sum to get:

$$\bbox[4px,border:5px groove green]{t=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(-e^{\frac{a-1}b}\right)^n}n\L_{n-1}^1\left(\frac nb\right)=1-\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{it}\ln\left(e^{-\frac{e^{it}}b-i t+\frac{a-1}b}(e^{it}+1)+1\right)dt}$$

The [sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2Bsum%5B%28-exp%28%28-3.5-1%29%2F4%29%29%5E%28n%29+%28LaguerreL%5B-1+%2B+n%2C+1%2C+n%2F4%5D%2Fn%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C30%7D%5D) and [integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1-Nintegrate%5B%28e%5E%28i+t%29+log%281+%2Be%5E%28-e%5E%28i+t%29%2F4+-+i+t%2B%28-3.5-1%29%2F4%29+%281+%2B+e%5E%28i+t%29%29%29%29%2F%282+%CF%80%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2%CF%80%7D%5D) [match](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=t%2B4+ln%28%281-t%29%2Ft%29%3D-3.5) the equation’s solution. The integral is almost like a [Cauchy integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$At+B\ln\left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)=x$$

We see, this is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($t$,$\ln\left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)$). The main theorem in [Ritt 1925] cannot help in these cases: We cannot read an [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) inverse function over a non-discrete domain directly from the equation because we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $t$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

Because we want to see if we can apply Lambert W, we transform the equation to an exponential polynomial. We want to transform $\ln\left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)$ to $e^y$ therefore.

$t\to\frac{1}{1+e^y}$:
$$\frac{A+By+Bye^y}{1+e^y}=x$$
$$A+By+Bye^y=(1+e^y)x$$

We see, this equation is an irreducible algebraic equation of both $y$ and $e^y$. According to the theorems in [Lin 1983] and [Chow 1999], such kind of equations cannot have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) or explicit elementary numbers respectively.

$$e^y=-\frac{By+A-x}{By-x}$$
$$\frac{By-x}{By+A-x}e^y=-1$$

We see, this equation cannot be solved in terms of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) but in terms of Generalized Lambert W:

$$\frac{y-\frac{x}{B}}{y-\frac{x-A}{B}}e^y=-1$$

$$y=W\left(^{\ \ \frac{x}{B}}_{\frac{x-A}{B}};-1\right)$$

$$t=\left(1+e^{W\left(^{\ \ \frac{x}{B}}_{\frac{x-A}{B}};-1\right)}\right)^{-1}$$

So we have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $t$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $t$.
$\ $

[[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/)

[[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43836165)

[[Chow 1999] Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)